# Regex Difference between Ruby & Python

Tags: python, ruby

I just started Advent of Code 2023 and am trying to use it to learn a few new programming languages. I have (some) familiarity with python, and literally just installed ruby today.

Day 1, part 2, I am using a Regex to search for digits as well as their spelled out versions. The regex in python (which yields the correct result):
`(?=(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine))`

When I use this exact regex in Ruby, I get a nil result. Interestingly, when I use this regex, I do get the exact same result in both python and ruby, but it is the incorrect answer:
`r"0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine"`

So I believe the answer has to do with the positive lookahead assertion, but I don't know why, and what it is doing differently.

Below are both of the files.

Python:

```
import re

input = open("../resources/input.txt","r")
lines = input.readlines()

targets = [
    '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
    'zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine'
]
values = {
    '0': 0,
    '1': 1,
    '2': 2,
    '3': 3,
    '4': 4,
    '5': 5,
    '6': 6,
    '7': 7,
    '8': 8,
    '9': 9,
    'zero': 0,
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4,
    'five': 5,
    'six': 6,
    'seven': 7,
    'eight': 8,
    'nine': 9
}

sum = 0

for line in lines:
    numbers = re.findall(r"(?=("+'|'.join(targets)+r"))", line)

    firstDigitValue = values[numbers[0]] * 10
    lastDigitValue = values[numbers[-1]]

    sum += (firstDigitValue+lastDigitValue)



print(sum)
```

Ruby:

```
# Init vars
sum = 0

reg = /\d|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine/
reg2 = /(?=(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine))/
reg3 = /0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine/

values = {
    '0' => 0,
    '1' => 1,
    '2' => 2,
    '3' => 3,
    '4' => 4,
    '5' => 5,
    '6' => 6,
    '7' => 7,
    '8' => 8,
    '9' => 9,
    'zero' => 0,
    'one' => 1,
    'two' => 2,
    'three' => 3,
    'four' => 4,
    'five' => 5,
    'six' => 6,
    'seven' => 7,
    'eight' => 8,
    'nine' => 9
}


# Pipe the file line by line and do per line
File.foreach("../resources/input.txt", chomp: true) do |line|
    # Get the first and last digits as their values
    numbers = line.scan(reg3)

    firstDigitValue = values[numbers[0]] * 10
    lastDigitValue = values[numbers[-1]]

    # accumulate
    sum += (firstDigitValue+lastDigitValue)

end

puts sum
```

Comment: Note `\d` matches 0 through 9. You don't have to write it all out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine
```

The problem with this regex, in both Python and Ruby, is that you fail to account for overlapping matches. I made the exact same mistake doing this problem earlier this month. If the phrase `eightwo`, for instance, appears in your puzzle input, then both Python and Ruby will match the "eight" part and then *start* looking for more matches at the "w", so they won't see the word "two".

```
(?=(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine))
```

This corrects the problem by putting the whole match into a lookahead (it's probably not efficient, but we're doing coding challenges so it's good enough). When considering overlaps, lookaheads aren't considered part of the pattern, so we start searching basically right where we left off.

However, in Ruby, when you have capture groups in your regular expression, then [`String#scan`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan) behaves differently.

> If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group.

So your output actually looks like

```
[["4"], ["one"], ["eight"], ["nine"]]
```

You just need to deal with this extra nesting layer.

```
first_digit_value = values[numbers[0][0]] * 10
last_digit_value = values[numbers[-1][0]]
```

Comment: I am marking this as the correct answer as it gets to the root of my issue being not understanding the difference between the output of python's re.findall method and ruby's scan method. Thank you very much. The regex itself, as I presumed, should be and is, the same: (?=(\d|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine))

Answer (score 4):

Let me begin by stating the problem for the benefit of those who have not delved into the Advent of Code website.

For each line of text the first and last names of digits in the string are to be extracted, joined and converted to an integer. These integers are then to be summed over all lines of the string.

The names of digits can either be a digit converted to a string or the word the digit is called. `'5'` or `'five'`, for example.

If the line were `'a7btwocfiveighty'`, `'7'` and `'eight'` would be extracted, `'eight'` would be converted to `'8'`, `'7'` and `'8'` would be joined to form `'78'` and that would be converted to the integer `78`. The lines `'a6b'` and `'csixd'` would both be converted to `66`.

Suppose the string were as follows.

```
two1nine
eightwothree
abcone2threexyz
xtwone3four
4nineeightseven2
zoneight234
7pqrstsixteen
```

The values computed for each line are 29, 83, 13, 24, 42, 14, and 76. These sum to 281.

---

Rather than using a positive lookahead, one can simply match each line against two regular expressions, one to extract the first string, the other to extract the last string, the two strings possibly being one and the same at the same starting location.

Let's form the two regular expressions using Ruby.

```
digits = (0..9).map(&:to_s)
  #=> ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

words = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five',
         'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']

word_to_digit = (digits.zip(digits) + words.zip(digits)).to_h
   #=> {"0"=>"0", "1"=>"1", "2"=>"2", "3"=>"3", "4"=>"4", "5"=>"5",
   #    "6"=>"6", "7"=>"7", "8"=>"8", "9"=>"9", "zero"=>"0",
   #    "one"=>"1", "two"=>"2", "three"=>"3", "four"=>"4", "five"=>"5",
   #    "six"=>"6", "seven"=>"7", "eight"=>"8", "nine"=>"9"}

alternation = word_to_digit.keys.join('|')
  #=> "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine"

rgx_first = Regexp.new(alternation)
  #=> /0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine/

rgx_last = Regexp.new(".*\\K(?:#{alternation})")
  #=> /.*\K(?:0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)/
```

---

If `str` is a given string, the total over all lines can be calculated at follows.

```
str.lines.sum do |line|
  (word_to_digit[line[rgx_first]] + word_to_digit[line[rgx_last]]).to_i
end
```

---

`rfx_first` is straightfoward, so I will not discuss that furrther.

`rgx_last` begins with `.*`, which consumes zero or more characters, *as many as possible*. It's greediness is what guarantees that it will return the correct key of `keys`, even when two keys overlap. If will merrily gobble up everything in its path, including elements of `keys`, until comes to the last element of `keys` in the string, and cannot go farther. `\K` resets the beginning of the match and discards all previously-consumed characters.

---

`rgx_last` can alternatively be defined as follows.

```
rgx_last = Regexp.new(".*(#{keys.join('|')})")
  #=> /.*(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)/
```

This removes `\K` and adds a capture group.

The subsequent code must then be changed as follows.

```
str.lines.sum do |line|
  (word_to_digit[line[rgx_first]] +
   word_to_digit[line.match(rgx_last).captures.first]).to_i
end
```

I mention this mainly because Python's standard regex engine does not support `\K` (though Python's PyPI engine does), whereas there is a Python equivalent to matching strings and extracting captured values.

Comment: I have not yet tested this code at the Advent of Code website but I think it should be OK on the basis of limited testing I have done with made-up data. I successfully passed part 1 of day 1 but then did something that messed up my account. I'll try again when I find time.